# Windows batch choice command for Windows XP & 2003

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

Is there a way to prompt users for input (ie: Yes/No) from a Windows batch script that works on XP and Windows 2003 server?  It seems some commands (ie: choice) only work on one OS and not others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [SET](http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm) command with the /P switch.

Comment: how about a timeout and a default?

Answer (score 6):

```
SET /P RESULT=Y or N?
ECHO %RESULT%
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that the `SET /P` command does not support all the same features as the `CHOICE` command. Namely:

- It doesn't restrict the user to entering a valid value
- The user has to press enter
- You have to check for casing differences (e.g. "A" vs "a")
- There is no way to default to a certain choice after a certain amount of time

For these reasons, I still prefer to use the `CHOICE` command rather than the `SET /P` command. To do this, you just need to include **CHOICE.COM** along with your batch file.  You can download **CHOICE.COM** from Microsoft via the *MS-DOS 6.22 Supplemental Disk*.  Here's the link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117600

Comment: I believe 64-bit Windows 7 includes `CHOICE.EXE`. At least, my machines have it and I'm pretty certain I didn't put it there myself.

Comment: You are correct @aphoria, mine has choice.exe and I didn't put it there either :)

Comment: The link to the DOS 6.22 utility is broken.  I had access to CHOICE.COM from Windows 98, but my XP system did not care for it; CHOICE.EXE from a 32-bit Windows 7 also didn't seem to work on a Windows XP system.  While I can't say this test system is "typical", my tests were sufficiently thorough such that this answer seems not viable in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This will basically mimic what choice does, you will need to put it as a subroutine in your batch file.  I also prefer choice but I need something portable that will run on Windows XP.

You can then modify this to accept other "choices," however this will work as case insensitive and repeat the prompt until the user explicitly enters Y, y, N, or n.

```
:yesorno
set /p choice=%2
if /i NOT %choice% == n (
    if /i NOT %choice% == y goto yesorno
)
set "%~1=%choice%"
goto :eof
```

You would then call this subroutine via:

```
call :yesorno answer "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: "
```

It's been working very well for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

For instance you could use this:

```
SET /P ANSWER=y OR n?
If "%answer%"=="y" goto yes
If "%answer%"=="n" goto no
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Windows Millenium's CHOICE.COM works fine for me under XP SP3.
However, mine is hungarian language, but you can probably find its original english variant, for example searching for "windows millenium ebd".

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=57468192666746678653

Comment: I've put it in C:\windows to be reachable from everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the solution directly in your answer. Also, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering